# How do I escape from the endless forest?

Tags: candy-box-2

I am equipped with:

- Monkey Wizard Staff (enchanted)
- Octopus King Crown (Jasper)
- Lightweight Body Armor
- Red Enchanted Gloves
- Boots of Introspection

For some odd reason, the forest has become endless for me. I have gained over 100000 candies and killed thousands of enemies. I have been going through this stage for about 25 minutes straight and it still hasn't showed a sign of ending. Please help me figure out why it won't stop. (I cant quit because then I would lose ALL of my candy I gained)

Comment: Which browser are you using? If the browser in question has a developer console enabled, are there any errors in the log?

Comment: I may be misremembering but don't the Boots of Introspection make you not move? So you are not walking through the forest, you are standing still. This is why it seems "endless".

Answer (score 4):

Wearing the [Boots of introspection](http://candybox2.gamepedia.com/Boots_of_Introspection) will prevent you from moving forward while touching the floor. You'll need to jump in order to go forward (while in the air) and that will make you able to reach the end of the level.